# How to check if data exists from multiple nested dict using Python

Tags: python

There are data with multiple nested structures as follows.

```
base = [
  {'id': 1, 'child_categories': [
    {'id': 11, 'child_categories': [
      {'id': 111, 'child_categories': [
        {'id': 1111, 'child_categories': []}
      ]},
    ]},
    {'id': 9999, 'child_categories': [
      {'id': 121, 'child_categories': []}
    ]},
  ]},
  {'id': 2, 'child_categories': [
    {'id': 21, 'child_categories': []},
  ]},
  {'id': 3, 'child_categories': [
    {'id': 31, 'child_categories': [
      {'id': 311, 'child_categories': []},
      {'id': 9999, 'child_categories': []},
    ]},
  ]},
  {'id': 4, 'child_categories': [], 'other_data': [
    {'id':9999, 'detail': 'detail_text'}
  ]},
  {'id': 9999, 'child_categories': [
    {'id': 333, 'child_categories': []},
  ]},
]
```

I want to implement processing to confirm that data of `id: 9999` exists from this data and delete it if it exists.
As a result of processing the image below is imagined.

```
result = [
  {'id': 1, 'child_categories': [
    {'id': 11, 'child_categories': [
      {'id': 111, 'child_categories': [
        {'id': 1111, 'child_categories': []}
      ]},
    ]}
  ]},
  {'id': 2, 'child_categories': [
    {'id': 21, 'child_categories': []},
  ]},
  {'id': 3, 'child_categories': [
    {'id': 31, 'child_categories': [
      {'id': 311, 'child_categories': []}
    ]},
  ]},
  {'id': 4, 'child_categories': [], 'other_data': [
    {'id':9999, 'detail': 'detail_text'}
  ]}
]
```

As a problem, rarely there is data like `'other_data': [{'id': 9999, 'detail': 'detail_text'}]`.
In this case I do not want to delete that data.
To the last, it is targeting data of `'id': 9999` at the first level in the list or data of`id': 9999` within `'child_categories'`.

Currently, I can only imagine the process of writing `for` many times.
I hope you will tell me a good way.

Comment: how can you tell the good (or bad) ones apart?

Comment: Please explain your problem briefly. Start with showing  the cases in which you would want to delete data containing id:9999, and cases in which you won't.

Comment: To the last, it is targeting data of ` 'id': 9999` at the first level in the list or data of `id': 9999` within 'child_categories'.

Comment: Have you tried anything? How about using a recursive function, that checks each dict and removes it if it is containing `'id': 9999`!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need some kind of recursive function like this:

```
def filter_data(data, id):
    " WARNING: this will edit data in-place! "
    for i, node in enumerate(data):
        if node['id'] == id:
            del data[i]
        leaves = node.get('child_categories')
        if leaves:
            filter_data(leaves, id)

filter_data(base, id=9999)
print(base)
```